# General way to get a value from a org.w3c.dom.Attr in Java 1.8?

Tags: java, xml, image

I'm looking for a completely general way to get the value from an XML attribute using Java 1.8's org.w3c.dom.Attr?

Here is what I tried:

```java
import org.w3c.dom.Attr;

String getAttributeValue(Attr attr) {
  if (attr.getSpecified()) {
    String value = attr.getValue();
  }
  else {
    throw new RuntimeException("I don't know how to get an attribute value when."
                             + "it is not specified with the attribute because my "
                             + "implementation does not consider default values in "
                             + "the schema.");
  }
}
```

According to the JavaDoc for org.w3c.dom.Attr, my solution is not complete because I don't cover the condition where a default value is given in the schema of the XML Document. How do I complete the algorithm covering all possible situations for which there is a correct solution and throwing an exception when a solution is not possible?

My Attr instance comes from a sequence of calls starting with  `javax.imageio.ImageIO.getImageReaders(ImageInputStream stream)`. It goes like this:

```java
void processImage(final ImageInputStream stream) throws IOException {
  Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream);
  while (readers.hasNext()) {
    ImageReader reader = readers.next();
    reader.setInput(imageInputStream, true);
    IIOMetadata metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0);
    String[] names = metadata.getMetadataFormatNames();
    int length = names.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
      Node node = metadata.getAsTree(names[i]);
      short type = node.getNodeType();
      if(type == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE) {
        System.out.print(name[i])
        System.out.print(" = ");
        String attributeValue = getAttributeValue(node);
        System.out.println(attributeValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to use a validating parser that will process the DTD for you; the API doesn't change but it will affect the return result

Comment: AlBlue's comment is interesting but fails my use case. I updated my question in such a way that the number of possible correct answers is reduced. The problem with AlBlue's answer is it requires me to exercise control over what XML parser is used.  I don't have that control in my use case.